Angular 18: ng build without browser folder
I am upgrading my Angular 17 application to Angular 18 and want to migrate to the new application builder.
I am using ng update @angular/core@18 @angular/cli@18 and opted in to the new application builder when I was asked. Next, I updated the angular.json file so that the browser build's location is using dist/project-x instead of dist/project-x/browser as suggested by the update process:

The output location of the browser build has been updated from dist/project-x to dist/project-x/browser. You might need to adjust your deployment pipeline or, as an alternative, set outputPath.browser to "" in order to maintain the previous functionality.

Here is an extract of my angular.json file:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "project-x": {
      // ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": {
              "base": "dist/project-x",
              "browser": ""
            },
            // ...
          },
          // ...
          "configurations": {
            // ...
            "development": {
              // ...
              "outputPath": {
                "base": "dist/project-x",
                "browser": ""
              }
            }
            // ...

ng build, ng build --configuration development and ng build --configuration production works as expected.
However, when overriding the output path in the command line, then it does not work as expected.
The command below, will create a folder browser in /projects/project-x-backend/:
ng build --base-href=/x/ --output-path=/projects/project-x-backend/wwwroot \
    --watch --configuration development --verbose

How can I get rid of the browser folder when using ng build --watch with a custom output path? (I would like to avoid setting the output path for the development configuration to /projects/project-x-backend/wwwroot in angular.json itself.)

@CesareIsHere answer below seems cleaner and more straight forward than the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78845873/2619537

It doesn't answer my question with the requirement: I would like to avoid setting the output path for the development configuration to /projects/project-x-backend/wwwroot in angular.json itself.

@CesareIsHere's answer is a global fix. If you want to set the output path for all configurations, this is is the way to go. However, I asked how to derivative from it when I use ng build --watch while leaving everything else in the configuration as is.

You're right. It solved my problem, but not yours.

Note: This answer is tailored towards the question itself (see question's comments why).
Scroll down to "Let's answer the question..." for the answer, but let me first point out the the global solution if you don't need to change the configuration for an alternative workflow...

Global Solution
If you want a global solution, the question itself points to the global fix too, or refer to one of the other answers.
"configurations": {
    // ...
    "development": {
      // ...
      "outputPath": {
        "base": "dist/project-x",
        "browser": ""
      }
    }
}


Let's answer the question...
I found a solution that works for me by adding an additional configuration (without needing to modify the development configuration) in angular.json and use the configuration in the command line:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "project-x": {
      // ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          // ...
          "configurations": {
            // ...
            "development": {
              // ...
            },

            "dev-watch": {

              // ... duplicate other configuration from development
              // then specify another outputPath:

              "outputPath": {
                "base": "/projects/project-x-backend/wwwroot",
                "browser": ""
              }

            }
            // ...

And then I execute ng build with:
ng build --base-href=/x/ --watch --configuration dev-watch --verbose


Reference to the Angular thread discussing this solution: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26304#issuecomment-1909967243

If you have the builder set to @angular-devkit/build-angular:application, the value cannot be an empty string.  I changed this to @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser per another answer and it encouraged me to delete that browser property altogether.  I ended up replacing it with "main": "src/main.ts"

I had a similar issue but I had to set the outputPath for my Angular 18 app to target the wwwroot folder in my WebApi project and got this extra browser folder. In this case a simpler solution would be just to update your angular default build configuration to include an empty value for browser field in outputPath, without creating a new configuration:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Client": {
      ..
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ..
          "options": {
            "outputPath": {
              "base": "../wwwroot",
              "browser": ""
            },


That solution works if you want this output path as a default. I'd like to avoid this. My issue was that I didn't want to set the output folder to wwwroot for all configurations. I just want to build to wwwroot if I run ng build --watch.

Thomas solution is nice, but i think that this is easier and works:
"outputPath": {
   "base": "./{{folder}}",
   "browser": ""
 },

And than simply use:
ng build

For example i'm using this solution to deploy build on firebase faster, so my config is something like this:
"outputPath": {
  "base": "./public",
  "browser": ""
},

Important: Use ./ before the path to select the project directory!

This is easier fix imo.

According to official documentation for Angular 18: https://angular.dev/tools/cli/build/

Applications generated by ng new use @angular-devkit/build-angular:application by default.


The default application configuration


builds an application with a client-side bundle, a Node server, and
build-time prerendered routes with esbuild.


The browser configuration


bundles a client-side application for use in a browser with Webpack.

So, in angular.json configuration file it's required to update the builder property value to browser instead of application one.
This will require also the change of browser required option to main, because it now can't be empty anymore in the application configuration.
Example of extract of default angular.json file:
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application", //default configuration
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts", // required property that can't be empty anymore
          },

Solution:
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser", // browser builder
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts", // migration of "browser" property to "main"
      }


Is the answer saying that, if you want to set build/options/browser to an empty string, like Remus does, you should change to setting build/options/main to an empty string, when upgrading to Angular 18? The answer doesn't show an empty string when setting its browser value.

This solution is working fine for me in Angular 18

The application flag generate a build for the browser and server. Use the browser-esbuild flag and you will just get the browser build ;)
Angular Builder

Angular team has updated the Angular CLI design to always output publicly accessible files in browser directory and the ssr files in server directory and other files such as statistics and licenses information in the root output path.
Do not use browser-esbuild option which is planned to be deprecated.
If you are using ASP.NET and Microsoft's SPA template and this update breaks the publish process, then the solution is very simple.

Go to the <project_name>.client folder in your solution.
Find <project_name>.client.esproj file and open it in a text editor.
There should be a build output in the xml document, something resembling $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\dist<project_name>.client\
Update this to $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\dist<project_name>.client\browser\

Now publish your application, it should create the release bundle without the browser folder in your wwwroot folder.
